# PHP regular expression with or operation

Tags: php, regex, wildcard

I would like to use a regex over strings like:

```
1-* or *-2.
```

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
"/(.*\-2)||(1\-.*)/"
```

but it doesn't seem to work - it returns true every time, regardless of my input string.

How can I create a regular expression to match these strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (simplistic) version:

```
/(^1-|-2$)/
```

If you need to match more specific, add `[0-9]` at the corresponding positions and maybe another anchor (`^$`).

```
/(^1-[0-9]$|^[0-9]-2$)/
```

Comment: I liked your previous answer; it was simple and elegant: /^1-|-2$/

Comment: @MrGoobri: but not correct ;) it would group like `/^1(-|-)2$/` and thus only match the string `1-2`

Comment: This returns true: preg_match("/^1-|-2$/", "3-2")

Comment: @MrGoobri: oh right. I was confusing precedence rules in regular expressions :-$

Answer (score 2):

Try this ...

```
"/(.+-\2)|(\1-.+)/"
```

Comment: Nope, this returns false: preg_match("/(.+-\2)|(\1-.+)/", "1-0")

Answer (score 1):

try this you need add ^ and $ to match the whole string:

```
/^(1-0|0-2)$/
```

or:

```
/^(1-.*|.*-2)$/
```

select whatever suits your needs

Comment: Nope, this returns false: preg_match("/^(.+-\2)|(\1-.+)$/", "1-0")

Comment: And this returns false too: preg_match("/^([1-9*]-[*1-9])$/", "1-0")

Comment: I would like 1-0 and 0-2 to match; I would like 2-0 and 0-1 to fail.

Comment: You previous second answer works. Thank you. You said this: /^(1-.*|.*-2)$/